# Berkshire script search on transaction

Tags: netsuite

phani kumar:
How to get line item values when I am doing script search on the invoice with the filter type is
 applying transaction as the payment.

Answer (score 0):

try using the filter ['mainline', 'is', 'F'] in your searches